# How to fetch 3 columns from the same row in the result?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to fix a code in an osCommerce store which is giving the following error on PHP 5.4:

> mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

This is the code:

```
$products = $cart->get_products();
    for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
    $id_produto = (INT)$products[$i]['id'];
    $sql = tep_db_query("SELECT p.manufacturers_id,m.manufacturers_cep,m.manufacturers_name FROM products p
    LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON m.manufacturers_id = p.manufacturers_id
    WHERE p.products_id = '$id_produto'")OR DIE(mysql_error());
    $id_fabricante = mysql_result($sql,'0','manufacturers_id');
    $cep_fabricante = mysql_result($sql,'0','manufacturers_cep');
    $nome_fabricante = mysql_result($sql,'0','manufacturers_name');

    $id_fabricantes[$id_fabricante]['peso'] += $products[$i]['quantity']*$products[$i]['weight'];
    $id_fabricantes[$id_fabricante]['cep'] = $cep_fabricante;
    $id_fabricantes[$id_fabricante]['nome'] = $nome_fabricante;

    }
```

I tried to change it and there are no more errors, but it's still not working. Is this the correct way to do it?

```
$products = $cart->get_products();
for ($i=0, $n=sizeof($products); $i<$n; $i++) {
$id_produto = (INT)$products[$i]['id'];
$sql = tep_db_query("SELECT p.manufacturers_id,m.manufacturers_cep,m.manufacturers_name FROM products p
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON m.manufacturers_id = p.manufacturers_id
WHERE p.products_id = '$id_produto'")OR DIE(mysql_error());

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$id_fabricante = $row['manufacturers_id'];

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$cep_fabricante = $row['manufacturers_cep'];

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$nome_fabricante = $row['manufacturers_name'];
    
$id_fabricantes[$id_fabricante]['peso'] += $products[$i]['quantity']*$products[$i]['weight'];
$id_fabricantes[$id_fabricante]['cep'] = $cep_fabricante;
$id_fabricantes[$id_fabricante]['nome'] = $nome_fabricante;

}
```

Comment: You cant mix `mysql` functions with `mysqli`, but in any way we would need to see `tep_db_query` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not correct. If you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php), you will see that the second parameter is the row to fetch in your result set. In your original example, you are fetching data only from the first row - `0` - and nothing else.

In your mysqli code, you fetch a new row before every assignment so the data will be a mix of the values of different fields from different rows.

The correct way would be something like:

```
// fetch the first row in the result set
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

$id_fabricante = $row['manufacturers_id'];
$cep_fabricante = $row['manufacturers_cep'];
$nome_fabricante = $row['manufacturers_name'];
```

Apart from that you would need to add error handling to make sure there is a row.

You should also try to avoid running sql queries in a loop. You could probably get all rows in 1 query using for example mysql's [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause and then you could loop over that result set.